# Turning a finite sequence of natural numbers into one natural number c++

Tags: c++, encoding

I have a sequence of natural numbers up to 72 digits, each digit varying from 0 to 9. I need to encode this sequence into one natural number. Using prime numbers (godel number) is not practical because the number gets really big really fast.

**Is there a different way of doing this?**

Comment: Even a single 72 digits number is big (doesn't fit in `uint64_t`)

Comment: Not sure what you're trying to achieve but I googled your question and found [this Math Overflow](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/69244/encoding-n-natural-numbers-into-one-and-back) question...

Comment: 72 digits? Or a sequence of 72 numbers from 0 to 9?

Comment: I wouldn't reinvent the wheel. There are BN libraries you can use to encode, decode and manipulate such numbers easily. Just search for "big numbers library X", X being your language of choice, and they'll pop up.

Comment: This sounds like you already have a 72-digit decimal big-integer, just manual.  Checkout real big-integer libraries, and you're done.